# Having trouble with my java factorial assignment

Tags: java, factorial

Can anyone help with my java factorial assignment? i think im doing it right but im not for sure. I need to have the user input a number and then calculate the factorials of the input number. Like is the person enter 10, the user would see this as an output:
0! = 1, 1! = 1, 2! = 2, 3! = 6, 4! = 24, 5! = 120, 6! = 720, 7! = 5040, 8! = 40320, 9! = 362880

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Factorial {

public static int factorial( int iNo ) {
    if (iNo < 0) throw
        new IllegalArgumentException("iNo must be >= 0");

    int factorial = 1;
    for(int i = 2 ; i <= iNo; i++)
        factorial *= i;
    System.out.println ( i + "! = " + factorial(i));

    return factorial ;
}
}
public class Factorial{
    public static void main ( String args[] ){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of factorials to calculate: " );
        int  iNo = input.nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i <= iNo; i++)
        factorial *= i;
        System.out.println ( i + "! = " + factorial(i));


}
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you having trouble reading input from user? Or generating factorials for all the numbers till the input number?

Comment: Did you run your method against your expected test cases and see the result you got back?  Essentially that'd be what we'd be doing as well, as there's nothing that immediately strikes me as "wrong" here...

Comment: `int` will **overflow** fairly quickly when you're using factorial.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch true, but using BigInteger might be a bit beyond the scope of the assignment.

Comment: So my problem is that i dont know how to print the factorials. If i input ten its supposed to look like this, nut i dont know how?

Comment: 0! = 1
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880

Comment: its supposed to print all of that out when i eneter 10. but not in a line like that, vertical and each on has its seperate line

Comment: @JackBracken I agree, but `long` *might be* in scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are almost there. You are missing some code in your `main`:

1. Prompt the user to enter a number. You can use `System.out.println` for that.
2. Read an `int` the user enters. You can use `Scanner.nextInt` for that.
3. Set up a `for` loop with variable `i` that goes from `0` to the number entered by the user.
4. Call `System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial(i))` in the body of the loop.

Once you finish the four steps above, you are done!

Comment: +1 Good and constructive advice without directly giving the answer.

Comment: import java.lang.Math;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Factorial {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ( "Enter number of factorials to calculate: " );
    iNo = input.nextInt();

    public static int factorial( int iNo ) {
        if (iNo < 0) throw
            new IllegalArgumentException("iNo must be >= 0");

        int factorial = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= iNo; i++)
            factorial *= i;

        return factorial;
    }

    public static void main ( String args[] ) {


    }
}
~
~
~

Comment: and is there anyway to do this without importing the java.lang.Math?

Comment: @ZacharyRW The code that you added goes *inside* the `main()` function, not outside it. Also, you need to declare `iNo` with an `int` in front of it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight does it look better now?

Comment: @ZacharyRW Yes, now you are left with the two last steps to complete.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but i already have the for loop and print statement up top. do i need to movie it all down?

Comment: @ZacharyRW Yes, there needs to be a separate loop in the `main`, right after reading an `int`. You are also missing a curly brace before the declaration of `main`, and the `import` does not belong inside `main`. You should undo the change to the loop inside factorial to start at 2, like it did in your original post, not at zero like it does now.

Comment: Can i get help on what the problem is now? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @ZacharyRW You have copied the same loop twice. It should be two different loops - inside different methods, with different limits, and different purposes. Take a look at [this link](http://ideone.com/zYgvHG) for your re-arranged program running on ideone.

Answer (score -1):

It's good, but you don't need the `}`.

```
import java.lang.Math;

    public class Factorial {



    public static int factorial( int iNo ) {

        // Make sure that the input argument is positive

        if (iNo < 0) throw
            new IllegalArgumentException("iNo must be >= 0");

        // Use simple look to compute factorial....

        int factorial = 1;
        for(int i = 2; i <= iNo; i++)
            factorial *= i;

        return factorial;
    }


    public static void main ( String args[] ) {




    }
```